# converting String to Calendar. What is the easiest way?

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, calendar

What is the simplest and easiest way to convert formatted String to Calendar?
For example 'dd.MM.yyyy' to Calendar?

Comment: Have you tried googling or using the search function here?

Comment: Of course I did. And didn't find any simple answer. Thanks for help...

Answer (score 35, accepted):

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Calendar cal  = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.setTime(df.parse(stringInstanceRepresentingDate));
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this piece of code:

```
String dateStr = "04/05/2010"; 

SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); 
Date dateObj = curFormater.parse(dateStr); 
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar .setTime(dateObj)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
Calendar calendarDate = Calendar.getInstance();
if (calendarDate!= null) {
strdate = sdf.format(calendarDate.getTime());
}
```